# onSaveInstanceState Não está gravando os dados

Tags: android

Tenho duas activities que vou chamar de activityA e acitivityB.

Na minha activityA eu tenho o seguinte método.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
       bundle.putString("ACTIVITY", "Dados que precisando ser salvos!");
       super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }
```

Quando vou para a ActivityB esse método acima é chamado. Mas quando volto para a ActivityA no metodo onCreate(); meu bundle está null.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        String teste = savedInstanceState.getString("ACTIVITY");
  }
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer por que?